# Store map objects inside of array

Tags: powershell

Currently I have an array of strings.

```
$vals = @()
$vals = $vals + $string
```

How can I store objects instead? F.e. just like in javascript:

```
{string: 'string', path: 'path'}
```

Is there an equivalent in powershell to store such objects?

Comment: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/using-variables-to-store-objects?view=powershell-7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of PowerShell 3.0 you can initialize a custom object with the following syntax:

```
[pscustomobject]@{string = 'string';path = 'path'}
```

So to add to a dynamically sized array, simply do:

```bsh
$vals = @()
$vals += [pscustomobject]@{string = 'string';path = 'path'}
```

Comment: Thank you, previously I checked wether a string already exists within the array like this `$vals -match $nr` - how can I check whether a string already exists in the array after using custom objects?

Comment: @Tim the default string representation of these custom objects will contain the first-level properties, so you should be able to do `$vals |Where {$_ -match $nr}` - but preferably you'd test against the expected property: `$vals |Where string -match $nr`